# Setpartpreamble and indent

Tags: indentation, koma-script, parts

how can I enforce an indent in a `\setpartpreamble` enviroment? Seems like `\indent` ain't working and a solution with `\hspace` seems to me like guessing the correct length of an indent.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,final]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{part}{0}
\setpartpreamble{
\vspace*{4\baselineskip}

In the first part of this book we shall become familiar with the central ingredients of the description of classical electrodynamics, that is the Maxwell equations. We first follow a “derivation” of these equations, suggested by Richard P. Feynman, and then introduce the scalar and the vector potential.

\hspace{0.1cm} Appropriate combinations of their derivatives represent solutions of the homogeneous Maxwell equations. The inhomogeneous ones provide us with coupled inhomogeneous wave equations for these potentials which are determined by the charge and the current densities. We can decouple these equations by taking advantage of the gauge freedom of electrodynamics. In the non-relativistic limit the Coulomb gauge is convenient and allows us to obtain a rather intuitive picture for the energy of the electromagnetic field as a sum of the energies of a continuous superposition of harmonic oscillators. 

The gauge freedom inherent in the Maxwell equations is also crucial in constructing the interaction of a charged particle with an electromagnetic field in quantum theory. The invariance of the Schrödinger equation under local phase transformation leads us to the minimal substitution which is at the very heart of Feynman’s derivation, as well as at the construction of the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian of a charged particle in an electromagnetic field described by classical mechanics.  
}
\part{Maxwell equations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I've added a slightly different patch for getting a standard vertical separation between part title and preamble. Note, however, that this will be used also for all the other preambles (chapter, for instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text of the part preamble is typeset in a `\parbox`, where the `\parindent` parameter is set to zero, so `\indent` does nothing.

In order to get the normal indentation, you have to save it somewhere and patch the preamble setting command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\set@@@@preamble}{#6}{\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}#6}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setpartpreamble{
In the first part of this book we shall become familiar with the central ingredients of the 
description of classical electrodynamics, that is the Maxwell equations. We first follow a 
“derivation” of these equations, suggested by Richard P. Feynman, and then introduce the 
scalar and the vector potential.

Appropriate combinations of their derivatives represent solutions of the homogeneous 
Maxwell equations. The inhomogeneous ones provide us with coupled inhomogeneous wave 
equations for these potentials which are determined by the charge and the current 
densities. We can decouple these equations by taking advantage of the gauge freedom of 
electrodynamics. In the non-relativistic limit the Coulomb gauge is convenient and allows 
us to obtain a rather intuitive picture for the energy of the electromagnetic field as a 
sum of the energies of a continuous superposition of harmonic oscillators.

The gauge freedom inherent in the Maxwell equations is also crucial in constructing the 
interaction of a charged particle with an electromagnetic field in quantum theory. The 
invariance of the Schrödinger equation under local phase transformation leads us to the 
minimal substitution which is at the very heart of Feynman’s derivation, as well as at the 
construction of the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian of a charged particle in an 
electromagnetic field described by classical mechanics.}

\part{Maxwell equations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a fixed vertical space between the part title and the preamble, add it to the patch, for instance with

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\set@@@@preamble}
  {#6}
  {\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}
   \vspace{4\baselineskip}
   %\noindent % uncomment if you want the first paragraph unindented
   #6}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```